# shell script создающий пустые файлы со всеми возможными правами доступа

Tags: linux, bash, unix, shell

Как написать shell script, который создаёт пустые файлы  со всеми возможными правами доступа. Имена файлов должны быть например такими: rwxrw_r__.txt.
Знаю, как это сделать вручную. Как пример:

```
   #!/bin/bash

   touch task5/rwxrwxrwx.txt | chmod 777 task5/rwxrwxrwx.txt
   touch task5/rwxr-xr-x.txt | chmod 755 task5/rwxr-xr-x.txt
   touch task5/rwx------.txt | chmod 700 task5/rwx------.txt
   touch task5/rw-rw-rw-.txt | chmod 666 task5/rw-rw-rw-.txt
   touch task5/rw-r--r--.txt | chmod 644 task5/rw-r--r--.txt
   touch task5/rw-------.txt | chmod 600 task5/rw-------.txt
```

НО как написать скрипт, который сам создаст по нужному шаблону текстовые файлы, и даст им права?
Ecть такое решение:

```
    p=( --- --x -w- -wx r-- r-x rw- rwx ) # the set of permissions 
    for u in "${p[@]}"; do for g in "${p[@]}"; do for o in 
   "${p[@]}"; 
    do
    f="task5/$u$g$o.txt"; touch -- "$f" && chmod "u=$u,g=$g,o=$o" -- 
   "$f" 
       done; done; done
Оно создаёт имена верно, но разрешения, которые даются иногда не совпадают с именами. Может, кто поможет откорректировать этот код?
```

Comment: `for i in $(seq 8*8*8); do umask $i; touch f$i; done` Это примерный первый шаг (из десятка, наверное, разных вариантов). Дальше сами.

Answer (score 1):

```
paste <(echo {0..7}{0..7}{0..7} |tr ' ' '\n') <(echo {-,r}{-,w}{-,x}{-,r}{-,w}{-,x}{-,r}{-,w}{-,x} |tr ' ' '\n') |awk '{z="-- "$2".txt";system("touch "z" && chmod "$1" "z)}'
```

с помощью `paste` сопоставляем столбцы полученные от перебора всевозможных значений для `{0..7}{0..7}{0..7}` и `{-,r}{-,w}{-,x}{-,r}{-,w}{-,x}{-,r}{-,w}{-,x}`

на выход получим примерно следующее:

```
000 ---------
001 --------x
...
774 rwxrwxr--
775 rwxrwxr-x
776 rwxrwxrw-
777 rwxrwxrwx
```

всего порядка 512 строк.

далее с помощью `awk` перебираем полученные данные создавая файлы имена которых соответствуют значениям из второго столбца, а права доступа с первого.

**п.с.**

если есть ограничения на открытие большого количества файлов то попробуйте один из вариантов:

```
paste <(echo {0..7}{0..7}{0..7} |tr ' ' '\n') <(echo {-,r}{-,w}{-,x}{-,r}{-,w}{-,x}{-,r}{-,w}{-,x} |tr ' ' '\n') |awk '{z="-- "$2".txt";system("touch "z" && chmod "$1" "z);close($2".txt")}'
```

---

```
paste <(echo {0..7}{0..7}{0..7} |tr ' ' '\n') <(echo {-,r}{-,w}{-,x}{-,r}{-,w}{-,x}{-,r}{-,w}{-,x} |tr ' ' '\n') |awk '{z="-- "$2".txt";x=system("touch "z" && chmod "$1" "z);close(x)}'
```

---

```
paste <(echo {0..7}{0..7}{0..7} |tr ' ' '\n') <(echo {-,r}{-,w}{-,x}{-,r}{-,w}{-,x}{-,r}{-,w}{-,x} |tr ' ' '\n') |awk '{z="-- "$2".txt";x=("touch "z" && chmod "$1" "z); x|getline; close(x)}'
```

где мы используем функцию `close()` для закрытия после каждого прохода.

**п.с.2**
еще один вариант:

```
paste <(echo {0..7}{0..7}{0..7} |tr ' ' '\n') <(echo {-,r}{-,w}{-,x}{-,r}{-,w}{-,x}{-,r}{-,w}{-,x} |tr ' ' '\n')| while read i; do eval $(echo "$i" |awk '{print "a="$1";b="$2}');touch -- $b".txt" && chmod $a -- $b".txt" ;done
```

Comment: спасибо, попробую

Comment: Zt. попробовал  выдаёт следующую ошибку:
 ./my_script.sh: cannot make pipe for process substitution: Too many open files
paste: /dev/fd/62: Too many open files. попробую сейчас это исправить.

Comment: @its-me, это однострочник, просто скопируйте в терминал и запустите, единственное пере запуском создайте папку и в ней уже запускайте, это для того чтобы легче потом почистить от нагенерированных файлов

Comment: к сожалению на сервере стоит лимит на открытые файлы (1024), пробовал его изменить - у меня нет прав это сделать. :(

Comment: сделал как вы сказали. та же самая ошибка выстреливает
-bash: cannot make pipe for process substitution: Too many open files
-bash: cannot make pipe for process substitution: Too many open files
-bash: cannot make pipe for process substitution: Too many open files
paste: /dev/fd/61: Too many open files

Comment: @its-me, добавил в ответ, попробуйте

Comment: спасибо за варианты. попробовал все три .  к сожалению, та же самая ошибка выскакивает :(

Comment: @its-me, а что показывают команды `cat /proc/sys/fs/file-max` и `ulimit -n` ?

Comment: @its-me, добавил в конце еще вариант, возможно поможет обойти ограничения

Comment: $ cat /proc/sys/fs/file-max 6815744

$ ulimit -n 1024

Comment: попробовал четвёртый вариант. та же самая ошибка, но строк с ошибкой меньше.

Comment: @its-me, странно, по идее 1024 должно хватать, похоже вы работаете в какой-то сильно ограниченной или нагруженной среде; ---- покажите еще `cat /proc/sys/fs/file-nr` и `ulimit -Hn` (Hard limit);  Также попробуйте перед выполнением задания в том же терминале выполнить команду  `ulimit -Sn $(ulimit -Hn)`, что установит (Soft limit) на максимум возможных открытий файлов для текущего сеанса.